# Strategy pattern on C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm trying port example of Strategy pattern from HeadFirst book from java to C++

```
#include "iostream" using namespace std;
class IFlyBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void fly() = 0;
};

class FlyWithWings : public IFlyBehavior
{
public:
    void fly() override
    {
        cout << "fly!";
    }
};
class FlyNoWay : public IFlyBehavior
{
public:
    void fly() override
    {
        cout << "no fly!";
    }
};

class IQuackBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void quack() = 0;
};
class Quack : public IQuackBehavior
{
public:
    void quack() override
    {
        cout << "Quack!";
    }
};
class Squeak : public IQuackBehavior
{
public:
    void quack() override
    {
        cout << "Squeak!";
    }
};
class MuteQuack : public IQuackBehavior
{
public:
    void quack() override
    {
        cout << "Can't quack";
    }
};

class Duck : public IFlyBehavior, IQuackBehavior
{
public:
    FlyWithWings* fly_behavior;
    Quack* quack_behavior;
    void swim()
    {
        cout << "Swim!";
    }
    virtual void display() = 0;
    void performQuack()
    {
        quack_behavior->quack();
    }
    void performFly()
    {
        fly_behavior->fly();
    }
};

class MallardDuck : public Duck
{
public:
    MallardDuck()
    {
        quack_behavior = new Quack();
        fly_behavior = new FlyWithWings();
    }

    void display() override
    {
        cout << "Mallard!";
    }
};
class RedheadDuck : public Duck
{
public:
    void display() override
    {
        cout << "RedHead!";
    }
};
class DecoyDuck : public Duck
{
public:
    void display() override
    {
        cout << "DecoyDuck!";
    }
};
class RubberDuck : Duck
{
public:
    void display() override
    {
        cout << "RubberDuck!";
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Duck* md = new MallardDuck;
    md->performFly();
    md->performFly();
    return 0;
}
```

But i got error:
 E0322 object of abstract class type "MallardDuck" is not allowed: Duck d:\Code\CODE\C++\Duck\Duck\Source.cpp 119
It's seems like compiler not see realized classes, why this happen? Any ideas about it? How I must do?

Comment: Don't use `new`!  Especially not as a C++ beginner.

Comment: What I have to use? Smart pointers?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot instantiate a `MallardDuck`, because a `MallardDuck` is a `Duck` which supposedly implements the `IQuackBehavior` interface but has failed to override `void Quack()`. Same for the flying behaviour.

I recommend that you do not try to "translate" Java to C++; they are completely different languages and should be treated as such. [Here are some good books for learning the language you're *actually* using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

`MallardDuck` inherits `Duck` which inherits from the abstract classes `IFlyBehavior` and `IQuackBehavior`. But nowhere do you override the abstract functions from those abstract classes.

Instead you seem to have a weird mix inheritance with encapsulation.